# Shortening unique identifiers

Tags: c++, uuid, poco

I am generating a UUID in the following way

```
 UUIDGenerator& generator = UUIDGenerator::defaultGenerator();
 UUID uuid2(generator.createRandom());
 return uuid2.toString() ; //returns f21cf9e1-feb1-4b44-9a24-11400b41d4e8
```

I want to know if there is a way of shortening this UUID preferably to 8 or fewer character ?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823 .  Of course, what you're allowed to do with a UUID depends on how that UUID is defined.  But, at least for the UUIDs used in Microsoft GUIDs, you can't chop them up.

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html , Java's UUIDs are also 128 bits.  They might format the output differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there's a way to shorten it.

You could simply chop off parts of it. You could hash it with a hash that generates shorter results. Run it through a compression algorithm. And many other simple, silly things.

Problem is; it wouldn't be a UUID any more.

Comment: I know java gives out shorter uids. I wonder if there is a way to generate shorter uids

Comment: "uid" != "uuid". Was that just a typo, or?

Comment: Yes that was a typo

Comment: I don't see how `Java` can generate a shorter value and it still being a `UUID`. A `UUID` is *by definition* ([see here, for example](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)) a 128 bit value. Sure, you can use a more compact *encoding* to make the human readable string shorter, but that does not intrinsically reduce the size - you still have to represent 128 bits.